# Как просуммировать таблицу из бд?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица в БД где у каждой записи есть своя цена, не понимаю как их просуммировать. array_sum() ругается на то что это string я попробовал применить explode но ему как то всё равно, всё равно выводиться последнее значение из таблицы. Мне нужно просуммировать все полученные значения из таблицы и вывести их на экран. Заранее спасибо.

```
  <?php   $sql2 = "SELECT `price` FROM `Ingredient` WHERE id_ingr = '1'"; 

              
                 if($result = $conn2->query($sql2)){
                    
                    foreach($result as $row ){
                        
                        $summ = $row['price'];
                        
                       
                    }
                }
              ?>
              <input type="text" class="Priceplate" name="price_P" value="<?php echo ($summ); ?>" readonly/>
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(price) AS price ...` и цикл при обработке в целом не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
$summ = $row['price'];
```

нужно

```
$summ += $row['price'];
```

Comment: Спасибо большое